# Rotate or transform 2 function

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have 2 non-linear functions of one variable, for simplicity lets say:

```
x = x(t) = t
y = y(t) = -t**2 + 8*t
```

I have an array for `t = np.linspace(0,2,20)`.

I can plot both `y` and `x` as functions of `t`, but i want a plot of `y` of `x`.

I know that this system is super easy to solve in reality i have a really non linear system, with both `x` and `y` non linear.

For exemple: `x = np.sqrt( t**2 + 1/(1+t**2) )`
and `y` something horrible i don't want to write but it has exponentials and fractions of `t**2`.

I want this graph: (Theoretical)

[image]

To become this graph: (Experimental)

[image]

I tried doing a rotation but that does't work because then i will have 2 values of y for 1 value of x.

If you have any questions, feel free to ask them, i will answer them.

Thank you

Edit: 
If i do plt.plot(x, y) i get this:
[image]

Comment: So you basically want a single line in a graph where you plot y as a function of x? Isn't it just `plt.plot(x, y)`? Either I underestimated your problem OR you explained it poorly. Which one is it?

Comment: yes, y as a function of x, or in the graphs, red as a function of blue. I don't want t on my plot

Comment: But what you want is essentially just plotting `plt.plot(x, y)`. Have you tried this? First compute x = f(t) and y = f(t) and then just use `plt.plot(x, y)`

Comment: Yep i've tried it and it is not the type of plot i want.

Comment: Then you have to provide a better example where x is not equal to t and then show what your desired plot should look like. I do not see currently, why `plt.plot(x, y)` doesn't give you what you want. It's mathematically straightforward; no hidden magic here

Comment: my desired plot is the second image and the real x is `x = np.sqrt( t**2 + 1/(1+t**2) )`, and the `y` i gave should work because it passes trough `x` at some `t`

Comment: Check the second image in my answer and tell me if this isn't what you want

Comment: May be what you want to do is plot `y-x` with `x` instead of `y` with `x`. So basically, `plt.plot(x, y-x)`?

Comment: if i do plt.plot(x, y) i get, the last image after the edit. Let me try (x, y-x)

Comment: Is that what you want? My last image is `plt.plot(x, y)`.

Comment: Yes, i think is the second: `plt.plot(x, y-x)`. Thanks so much. And i'm sorry for my bad explanations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you just want to plot `y` as a function of `x`, where both `x` and `y` depend on `t`. You can simply do `plt.plot(x, y-x)` to get a relative difference. See my example below for a non-linear system. Compare both the figures.

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(8, 3))

```
t = np.linspace(0,2,20)

x = np.sqrt( t**2 + 1./(1+t**2) )
y = -t**2 + 8*t

ax[0].plot(t, x, '-r', label='x')
ax[0].plot(t, y, '-b', label='y')
ax[0].set_xlabel('t')
ax[0].legend()

ax[1].plot(x, y-x, '-b')
ax[1].set_xlabel('x')
ax[1].set_ylabel('y')
```

[image]